# Can I call SFRestRequest more than once from within ViewDidLoad method?

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I want to executue two or more SOQL queries from the `ViewDidLoad` method, e.g., return a particular list of customers, return a particular list of cases etc. How can this be done? I have experimented by trying to setup `request1` variable and `request2` variables but I get stuck when passing into `request(SFRequest *)request didLoadResponse` as I can only call this once. Below is the relevant pieces of code:

```
SFRestRequest *request1 = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account"];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request1 delegate:self];
```

As far as I can see, this then gets passed on to

```
- (void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(id)jsonResponse {
    NSArray *records = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"records"];
    self.dataCustomerDetailRows = records;
    [self.tableCustomerList reloadData];
```

Can you outline a way of running the two queries and passing the results back into the two `tableViews` within the `view`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to keep a reference to the `SFRestRequest` objects you create and, in your response delegate method, determine which request has just completed and process accordingly.

A far better option, in my (not-so) humble opinion, is to use the [nifty block interfaces](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/native/SalesforceNativeSDK/SalesforceNativeSDK/Classes/SFRestAPI%2BBlocks.h) I contributed to the SDK. :)