# problem returning results from several SFRestRequest at the same time

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am currently trying to execute a few SOQL queries using the SFRestRequest method and have the results stored in NSArrays. Below is my code, but the problem I run into is that the methods inside ViewDdidLoad get executed before the results are returned from the query. I think I need to create separate SFRestRequests but how would I do this?

```
- (void)getA {
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT id,name from account LIMIT 10"];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)getB {
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT id, lastname from contact LIMIT 10"];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableviewLastMonthTop10 reloadData];
[self.tableviewCFYTDTop10 reloadData];
self.getA;
self.getB;

}


-(void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(id)jsonResponse {
    NSArray *records = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"records"];
    self.arrayA = records;
    NSLog(@"%@",records.description);
        [self.tableviewA reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine which response you're processing in `request:didLoadResponse:` since you have two queries going (`getA` and `getB`). Also, you're storing the results in the same array, which is probably not your intent. You need to call `reloadData` on the appropriate tables after loading the responses into memory. This is the nature of asynchronous code. The `request` object contains the origin of the request (e.g. what was queried), and `jsonResponse` has the values of the response. You will need to send the appropriate `reloadData` message depending on the results. You could check the first entry of the records array to see if attributes/type is Account or Contact, then reload the appropriate table. I'm still a novice at Objective-C (just started last week), so I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader (someone is welcome to update this answer with code snippets).

### Edit #1

Also, see the answer from [Can I call SFRestRequest more than once from within ViewDidLoad method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/can-i-call-sfrestrequest-more-than-once-from-within-viewdidload-method?rq=1) for a cleaner solution: simply use the block methods available in order to direct your code flow to the correct array/table.

Comment: I need help using the block methods, can you show me sample code?

Comment: BTW, the answer you link to is the answer to my first question on this matter, although the answer was too high level for me to be able to determine a solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll update my answer as soon as practical. As I stated, Objective-C is *really* new to me, even though I code in 20 ('ish) other languages. I should be able to get a working model up fairly shortly though.

Comment: much appreciated, I hope to be able to return the favour some day soon!